# Jetty SSL port does not close even maxIdleTime is reached

Tags: java, jetty

We have enabled Jetty SSL port as 7443. MaxIdle time is set to 90000 ms. 5
connections were established on this port. These connections were not closed
even after 10 minutes.

The same scenario is working fine with Jetty non-ssl port 7080.

Please let us know if this is an known issue.

Answer (score 0):

"MaxIdle" time denotes the time after the last byte was read/written from that connection. If the response is still being written, then the connection might not get reset.